# Highlight gridview row in update panel without posting back

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in an update panel with the following code to select a row, this in turn updates another updatepanel with details from the form record.

```
protected void gvMainGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //Make the entire row clickable to select this record
            //Uses javascript to post page back
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gvMainGrid, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex));   

        }
    }
```

I am manually binding the gridview from a database and don't want to rebind the grid just to highlight the row, but I can't seem to add any javascript to the onclick event, it seems to either show the GetPostBackClientHyperlink or the row highlight javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struggling to add both on click events to the row databound:

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gvMainGrid, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex));   

e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "onGridViewRowSelected('" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString() + "')");
```

Appending the PostBack select after the row highlight method with ';' seems to have worked.

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "onGridViewRowSelected('" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString() + "');" + ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gvMainGrid, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex));
```

Answer (score 3):

[How to highlight gridview when row is selected](http://www.netomatix.com/development/GridViewRowSelectedStyle.aspx)

for this you have to write this code in your code behind file in OnRowCreated event or your can also write this code in OnRowDataBound event of grid...

```
    protected void ctlGridView_OnRowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {    
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "onGridViewRowSelected('" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString() + "')");
        }            
    }
```

and add this one script

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var gridViewCtlId = '<%=ctlGridView.ClientID%>';
    var gridViewCtl = null;
    var curSelRow = null;
    function getGridViewControl()
    {
        if (null == gridViewCtl)
        {
            gridViewCtl = document.getElementById(gridViewCtlId);
        }
    }

    function onGridViewRowSelected(rowIdx)
    {
        var selRow = getSelectedRow(rowIdx);
        if (curSelRow != null)
        {
            curSelRow.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
        }

        if (null != selRow)
        {
            curSelRow = selRow;
            curSelRow.style.backgroundColor = '#ababab';
        }
    }

    function getSelectedRow(rowIdx)
    {
        getGridViewControl();
        if (null != gridViewCtl)
        {
            return gridViewCtl.rows[rowIdx];
        }
        return null;
    }
</script>
```

and it will highlight the selected row..

Comment: I should have mentioned I had code to do the highlight, it was adding this and the select together that was the problem.

This code is an improvement on mine +1 thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can't apply text-decoration to a <tr>... or a <td> for that matter.  You need to apply it to the elements inside.

Here are a couple adjustments you can try-

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.cursor='hand';";



e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gvMainGrid.ClientId, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex));
```

The 1st works for me in code.  Didn't have anything handy to test the 2nd.