# Getting event fired control cell of the grid view in Row command event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowcommand, datagridviewcellstyle

Can anybody please help me to get the cell index of the event fired control in row command of the grid view. I have one radio button control in side my grid view. If the user clicks on the radio button, i need to change the background color of the particular cell. Please help me to resolve this. My code is showing below.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MD-R">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgMDR" runat="server" ImageUrl="" ToolTip='<%# Eval("MDR") %>'
                            CommandName="MDR" CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>'
                            OnClientClick="javascript:return ConfirmReport(this);" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery:**

```
function ConfirmReport(obj) {
   $("tr").removeClass("selectedrow");
   $(obj).closest('tr').addClass("selectedrow");
 }
```

**CSS:**

```
.selectedrow
{
background:green;
}
```

For code behind row selection, refer the below link.

[Highlight gridview row in update panel without posting back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429576/highlight-gridview-row-in-update-panel-without-posting-back)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need
1.  to do dynamically. Not in JQuery
2.  to change the particular cell only. Not the entire Row.

Comment: @mac, dynamically means?

Comment: @MAC, Please refer the below link for code behind row highlight selectionhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429576/highlight-gridview-row-in-update-panel-without-posting-back